# How to set a store root category

Tags: category, magento-2.1, resource-model, stores

I want to set the root category of a new batch created store.

I'm looking for something like :

```
$store->setRootCategory($rootCategoryId);
```

But it looks like it does not exists, despite there is a $store->getRootCategory() method.

I found a method in the Category Model: $category->setStoreId($storeId) but since a Category may be used by several stores as root category, it's probably not the right way do it ? is it ?

I'm a bit lost on that case, any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root category ID is in the 'store group' entity. Try this:

```
    $group = $store->getGroup();
    $group->setRootCategoryId($rootCategoryId);
    try {
        $group->save();
    }catch (\Exception $e) {

    }
```

Comment: In case it helps : since it was for a newly created store, I needed to create a new group instead of getting it with `$store->getGroup();` which in this case, just return `false`